# Lua loop shuffle list

Tags: lua

i have a problem with my Script if i try to loop thought my list the output is completly random shuffled

minimal Code:

```
list = {
    numbers = {
        number1 = 1,
        number2 = 2,
        number3 = 3,
        number4 = 4,
        number5 = 5,
        number6 = 6,
        number7 = 7,
    }
}

for k, numbers in pairs(list) do
    for k, number in pairs(numbers) do
        print(number)
    end
end
```

output:

```
5
7
2
3
4
6
1
```

the only fix i figured out is to remove the variables number1 to number7
and just enter the numbers

Comment: Thats normal for beginers in Lua (MeToo). You have to understand that a table index key only is auto numbered and then in a sequence when not using index keys that are strings and therefore hashed and therefore not in sequence and appearing randomly each new script runtime. Example of defining auto indexed (from 1 to 3) table values:```tab = {"One", "Two", "Three"}``` will be always in order with ```print(table.concat(tab,'\n'))``` or your ```pairs(list)``` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Lua tables do not have an order.

In addition to that you're using `pairs` which internally uses `next`.

From the Lua manual:

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even
> for numeric indices. (To traverse a table in numerical order, use a
> numerical for.)

In your case the keys have a numeric component so you could simply create them in a numeric loop.

```
local numbers = {
        number1 = 1,
        number2 = 2,
        number3 = 3,
        number4 = 4,
        number5 = 5,
        number6 = 6,
        number7 = 7,
    }

for i = 1, 7 do
  print(numbers["number"..i])
end
```

For other non-numeric keys you would have to use a second table that lists the keys in an ordered sequence:

```
local numbers = { bob = 1, bill = 3, john = 2}
local orderedKeys = { "bob", "john", "bill"}

for k,v in ipairs(orderedKeys) do
  print(numbers[v])
end
```

A numeric loop will always work for any integer keys.

```
local numbers = {
  [0] = 0,
  [5] = 5,
  [3] = 3,
  [1] = 0,
}

for i = 0, 5 do
  if numbers[i] then
    print(numbers[i])
  end
end
```

Read through this carefully:

> A table with exactly one border is called a sequence. For instance,
> the table {10, 20, 30, 40, 50} is a sequence, as it has only one
> border (5). The table {10, 20, 30, nil, 50} has two borders (3 and 5),
> and therefore it is not a sequence. (The nil at index 4 is called a
> hole.) The table {nil, 20, 30, nil, nil, 60, nil} has three borders
> (0, 3, and 6) and three holes (at indices 1, 4, and 5), so it is not a
> sequence, too. The table {} is a sequence with border 0. Note that
> non-natural keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.

Things like `ipairs`, the length operator `#`, `table.sort`, `table.concat` and others only work with sequences.

Keys that do not contribute to the sequence are ignored by those functions. You can only loop over all keys of a table with next or  pairs respectively. But then order is not guaranteed.